# Comprehensive map/list of active Orthodox synagogues in the U.S

Tags: technology, synagogue, minyan, united-states, geography

Does anyone know of a map or list of all the active Orthodox shuls in the U.S.? When I was looking for which residencies to apply to it was my limiting factor and sometimes it was hard to find out where the shuls were. It would also be interesting to see which areas across the map have Orthodox communities.

If they doesn't exist, how difficult do you think it would be to make one?

Comment: Somewhat related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66305 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14387

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Check out this site](https://www.godaven.com/).

Click on each state to get cities and then click on each city to get a list of just about (if not all) the minyanim in that city.

Comment: http://www.minyanmaps.com/ also

Comment: Thank you. I was familiar with godaven but didn't realize there was a browse option.

Comment: @sye81397, why don't you post an answer?

Comment: is  a comment not good enough ?!

Comment: @sye81397, I'm not sure how good their site mainenance is, they list a schul in my area which hasn't existed for upwards of 15 years and another which doesn't daven in their building any longer.

Answer (score 2):

I like the Kosher GPS App which gives me minyanim and links to their davening times, kosher restaurants, with links to their websites, and mikvaot.  Map directions are available for each.

Comment: Sounds useful.  Do you have download link(s)?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Check your app store.  I have it for I-Phone.  I don't know if one exists for other operating systems.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the OU's synagogue finderlocator: https://www.ou.org/synagogue-finder/. (It lists both synagogues that are OU members and those that are not.)

Answer (score 0):

Check this site out also , http://www.minyanmaps.com/

Might not be good though, like @Noach Mi Frankfurt said.